how to load gltf files in a Webpack 5 app?
I am starting a project with babylon js and webpack 5 and I have to load some gltf files in my project but I am always getting the following error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
  here is the relevent part of my webpack.config.js file      

 //webpack.config.js 
module: {         
 rules: [  
            {
test: /\.tsx?$/,                 
 use: "ts-loader",                  
exclude: /node_modules/,              },                        
 ],      
},  

I have followed the official documentation of babylon about loading gltf models however it does not work. I am not an expert at webpack but I think I am missing something. Do someone knows what I need to modify in my config ?  Do you think I should give up on webpack 5 and just use webpack 4 ? 

I tried alot of things such as adding the following rule :
 {
                test: /\.(gltf|.glb)$/i,
                        type : 'asset',
                }
I made sure that the gltf files are where I want them to be. 

I expect to be able to write the following line of code in my index.ts 

BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh('assets/', 'skull.gltf', scene) 

(I have assets in my src/ folder) to be able to load my skull in my scene.
I am developping under wsl 2 Ubuntu distro, my nvm config is : node : default -> v18.20.3
I have npm and nvm according to this node version. I tried updating node using a more recent version but it seems that babylon and webpack do not like it so I am using lts/hydrogen. Do not hesitate to ask me to provide more informations if you feel like it would help you understand my context. I don't find any clear solutiion on the internet to solve this issue, I would take any piece of advice to help me move forward with this issue. 

